# How to make a custom Authentication Provider in Symfony 4?

Tags: php, symfony, web

I want to make a custom Authentication Provider, but I really don't know how to start, the thing is that we just want to store users's email in database, nothing else.

Every month, a password will change, and that password is used by every user to let them access the site. The login form will so look like:

- An email field to store the email in database
- A password field but it's not stored with the user it's just one password for everybody.

I don't know if I must store the same password for each user in database or something else... I want the users be identified as "logged in" by symfony, I know I have to make a custom authentication provider but I don't know how... Thanks for your help.

Comment: That's literally in the docs: [How to Create a custom Authentication Provider](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/custom_authentication_provider.html)

Comment: You don't need a full blown authentication provider for this.  You can plug in your own password encoder in the encoders section of your security config file.  You can inject your master password and then tweak the MyEncoder::isPasswordValid() method.

Comment: Thanks! I'm gonna try with the PasswordEncoder solution.

Comment: Now I have another problem, when a user doesn't exist, email should be stored in database but how do I do that on the login form? Can we just "override" the login logic of symfony?

Comment: The easiest way might be to make a [custom User Provider](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/custom_provider.html).  The provider is always called on login and could then check the database and add the user if they don't already exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for those who are looking for a solution for this problem, I solved it like this: I made a custom UserProvider. This is for creating the user in the database if he don't exist. (look the `loadUserByUsername` function)

```
<?php

namespace App\Security\User;

use App\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UsernameNotFoundException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UnsupportedUserException;
use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;

class CustomProvider implements UserProviderInterface
{
    private $repository;
    private $em;

    public function __construct(UserRepository $repository, EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $this->repository = $repository;
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function loadUserByUsername($username)
    {
        $userData = $this->repository->findOneByEmail($username);
        $password = 'secure_p@ssw0rd';
        $user = new User($username, $password);

        if (!$userData) {
            $user = new User($username, $password);
            $this->em->persist($user);
            $this->em->flush();
        }
        return $user;
    }

    public function refreshUser(UserInterface $user)
    {
        if (!$user instanceof User) {
            throw new UnsupportedUserException(
                sprintf('Instances of "%s" are not supported.', get_class($user))
            );
        }

        return $this->loadUserByUsername($user->getUsername());
    }

    public function supportsClass($class)
    {
        return User::class === $class;
    }
}
```

Then I made a custom User class (I just store email in the database, nothing else):

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="leclan_users")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Email()
     */
    private $email;

    private $password;

    private $roles = [];

    public function __construct($email, $password, array $roles = array())
    {
        $this->email = $email;
        $this->password = $password;
        $this->roles = $roles;
    }

    public function getId(): int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getUsername(): ?string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function getEmail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail(string $email): void
    {
        $this->email = $email;
    }

    public function getPassword(): ?string
    {
        return 'secure_p@ssw0rd';
    }

    public function setPassword(string $password): void
    {
        $this->password = $password;
    }

    public function getRoles(): array
    {
        $roles = $this->roles;
        if (empty($roles)) {
            $roles[] = 'ROLE_USER';
        }
        return array_unique($roles);
    }

    public function setRoles(array $roles): void
    {
        $this->roles = $roles;
    }

    public function getSalt(): ?string
    {
        return null;
    }

    public function eraseCredentials(): void
    {
    }

    public function serialize(): string
    {
        return serialize([$this->id, $this->email]);
    }

    public function unserialize($serialized): void
    {
        [$this->id, $this->email] = unserialize($serialized, ['allowed_classes' => false]);
    }
}
```

And then for the password tweak I used a custom PasswordEncoder:

```
<?php

namespace App\Security\Encoder;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\BasePasswordEncoder;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\BadCredentialsException;

class CustomEncoder extends BasePasswordEncoder
{
    public function encodePassword($raw, $salt)
    {
        return '';
    }

    public function isPasswordValid($encoded, $raw, $salt)
    {
        if ($this->isPasswordTooLong($raw)) {
            return false;
        }

        if ($raw === 'secure_p@ssw0rd') {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

This method works fine, but I'm not sure about the `encodePassword` method (Is it fine if I just return an empty string? I'm not using the method at all.)

Also this is my security.yaml file:

```
security:
    encoders:
        App\Entity\User:
            id: App\Security\Encoder\CustomEncoder

    providers:
        custom:
            id: App\Security\User\CustomProvider

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            anonymous: true
            provider: custom
            form_login:
                login_path: security_login
                default_target_path: app_main
                check_path: security_login
            logout:
                path: security_logout
                target: security_login

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

Thanks @Cerad who gave me this solution

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you have a very customized authentication procedure. For this I recommend using the [GuardAuthenticator](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/guard_authentication.html). The first question you had is a bit complicated to solve with this, so let me take you through the authentication process as I understand it.

1. supports

   This should probably always return true, as you always want to use this authentication system.
2. getCredentials

   This is were I would check for 2 things. Either we are trying to login, so I would check whether the request is on the login-path and a POST-method or if a session-key, that identifies a previously authored user, is set. If neither is true, we just return null and skip the rest of the authentication.
3. getUser

   Either we read the user from the session (if they previously logged in) or we look for the username in the submitted request data.
4. checkCredentials

   When we previously logged in we can just return true. If we are in the middle of authentication (the POST-request to login-path), we just check in the master password-table if the provided password matches our current master password.

   Note: You can still use for example Symfony's PasswordEncoders like bcrypt, but it might be more work. Feel free to ask a follow up question.
5. onAuthenticationSuccess

   We save the user data to the session.
6. onAuthenticationFailure

   Here is where I would implement your second scenario, where you create a new user based on the provided input.

Feel free to ask a question if you need more details, than this general outline.

edit for clarification: I wrote storing/getting a value from the session. For this you should use Symfony's TokenStorage. This will make the user available like with a normal login. If you manually store it in a session you might have to tweak things to make it play nicely after authentication.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that! I think this is a cleaner way do do this but I created a custom UserProvider and a custom PasswordEncoder and it work well (thanks to @Cerad). I will post what I've made when it will be finished.